# Creating a mailto link with auto link generation

Tags: html, email

I know how to make a standard mailto link to allow users of a webpage to email an email address. However, I'm looking to create a 'share link', so when one clicks on the link the link of that page/URL is entered into the email body to share.

How is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you want, but I think you might think of this.

```
<a href="mailto:example@example.com?body=Hello%20Fritz,%0D%0A%0D%0Asome%20text">Mail with predefined body</a>
```

This syntax is: `mailto:[mail-address]?body=[urlencoded-text]&subject=[urlencoded-text]`

It's not an W3C standard but some mail clients support it.

Comment: Well I'm trying to get a mailto link which when it opens the emal client to send an email, it will also include, in the body of the email, the URL of the page on which the mailto link was clicked.

Essentially, it's going to be a 'share this with a friend' type link where the person can share the URL via email without having to copy and paste the URL manually. It should be present in the email body.

Comment: That's exactly what I described.

Comment: So because this will require the user to enter in the email address (since they are sharing it with someone else), is the mail-address field to be left blank, or with a '?'